# Bug ao carregar imagnes com owl-carousel

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

Bom dia pessoal, 
Por favor me ajudem com este problema e desde já agradeço.
Eu tenho uma lista de imagens e dados que não são carregadas de forma imediata e sincronizada ao carregar a página pela primeira vez, sempre a imagem do último item do carousel fica totalmente ajustada a div pai que envolve o carousel tendo, 100% de altura e 100% de largura, porém apenas por 1 segundo aproximadamente, isso em todos os navegadores.

Segue dois prints que retratam este problema.

**Fica todo esticado ao carregar a página pela primeira vez apenas.**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**As imagens ficam normal, após 1 segundo do bug.**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Obs.** Es te problema sempre ocorre com o último item do carousel, independentemente da quantidade de items.

Código HTML (Está agrupado, pois é grande):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Chamada CSS:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/external/owl.carousel.min.css">
```

**Chamada dos scripts:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/external/owl.carousel.min.css}">


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/external/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/external/owl-carousel/config-home-user.js"></script>
```

**Configuração do carousel:**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    // CONFIG CAROUSEL OF THE HOME USER
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        stagePadding: 50,
        loop: true,
        margin: 0,
        nav: true,
        margin: 20,
        autoWidth: false,
        navText: ['<i class="far fa-angle-left" title="Anterior"></i>', '<i class="far fa-angle-right" title="Seguinte"></i>'],
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1,
                loop:false
            },
            500: {
                items: 2,
                loop:false
            },
            800: {
                items: 3,
                loop:false
            },
            1000: {
                items: 4,
                loop:false
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Jovem coloque também seu html e se usou algum CSS. Se tiver um link para o seu projeto melhor ainda!

Comment: Provavelmente isto é por causa que ele ainda esta renderizando a pagina e não chamou sua função `owlCarousel`. Eu tinha esse problema tenta iniciar com `display: none` no seu carousel e então apos chamar a função `owlCarousel` retira o `display: none` com `jquery`.

Comment: Na verdade isso deve estar acontecendo com todos os itens, e só aparece o último porque ele fica por cima dos outros. O interessante é fazer mais ou menos como o amigo Erick falou, mas em vez de `display: none` eu colocaria `opacity: 0` e após o carregamento da página, `opacity: 1`...

Comment: Vc pode tentar por `rel="preload"` nas tag que indexa os scripts para ver se carrega primeiro e melhora esse bug

Comment: Obrigado pessoal, verdade!
Deu certo com a solução proposta pelo **dvd**.
Realmente o renderizado demorava um pouco mais, por ter muita coisa na página, assim como Erick Zanetti falou. 

Muito obrigado a todos que tentaram ajudar.